# Impact of various kinds of noise on calculation of operator's expectation value

Tags: noise, qiskit

I am trying to calculate the expectation value of an operator `Op` on Qiskit's simulator with noise present. I am trying to study the impact of various kinds of noises on the quality of the result. The NoiseModel class in Qiskit has parameters corresponding to various kinds of noise. Which one(s) of them affects the computation of the expectation value the most? What I am trying to do is to switch off or scale down various types of noise and measure its impact on the calculated expectation value.

Comment: What do you mean by "affects the computation of the expectation value the most" ?

Comment: @Johan-Luca I am thinking of scaling down one of the various kinds of noises in the `NoiseModel` and then calculating the expectation value on the simulator. Scaling down which one of these noises will bring the simulation result close to the ideal result the fastest?